# 500 Internal Server Error because of htaccess in cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have uploaded my site on live which is in cakephp 1.3.

Site have two part **admin** and **web**

admin part is working fine but web part is not working, if i removed .htaccess then its working fine.

My .htaccess rules are

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /imsjobportal/
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule ^$ web/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) web/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But web part is not working, can anyone suggest me what is the issue?

`http://project-in-progress.com/imsjobportal/admin/` url worked

`http://project-in-progress.com/imsjobportal/` url not working

Comment: Did you look in the error log of PHP or the web server to see why the 500 error is encountered?

Comment: 500 errors are generally detailed in the server's error log. look for there for why you're getting it.

Comment: error log is not generate.

Comment: I am using 1and1 linux server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the htaccess file is in your `/imsjobportal/` directory, it's probably this rule that is looping:

```
RewriteRule (.*) web/webroot/$1 [L]
```

You need to add a condition to prevent the looping:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/web/webroot/
RewriteRule (.*) web/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  - RewriteRule (.*) web/webroot/$1 [L] - and then check, it should work then.